# Is java.secure.random a sufficient choice for gambling industry?

Tags: java, algorithm, random, prng

Java provides an cryptographically secure random number generator in the package java.secure.random.

Is it possible to use this number generator if I consider things like seeding and cyclic re-instantiation of the RNG? Or can I use the number generator 'as it is'?

Has anyone experience with this generator?

**EDIT**: the requirements are:

a) Be statistically independent

b) Be fairly distributed (within statistically expected bounds) over their range

c) Pass various recognized statistical tests

d) Be cryptographically strong.

Comment: Exploring this problem further, I just noticed that the last-resort SecureRandom generator is SHA1.  It's possible they're doing something other than the obvious; otherwise SHA1 has an internal state of 160 bits, which is not sufficient to shuffle a single deck of cards.  It would mean that no matter what you did to your RNG or your shuffle algorithm, it would still be limited to producing only a subset of possible permutations.  Strictly this does not appear as one of your requirements; so maybe that's OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others say, the secure RNG can have limited throughput.  To mitigate this
you can either stretch that secure randomness by seeding a CPRNG, or you can
try to optimise your usage of the bitstream.

To shuffle a pack of cards, for example, you need only 226 bits, but a naive
algorithm (calling `nextInt(n)` for each card) will likely use 1600 or 3200
bits, wasting 85% of your entropy and making you seven times more susceptible
to delays.

For this situation I think the [Doctor Jacques
method](https://web.archive.org/web/20171012154111/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65653.html) would be appropriate.

To go with that, here's some performance analysis against progressively more
costly entropy sources (also contains code):

[Bit recycling for scaling random number generators](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.4290.pdf)

I would lean towards efficient usage rather than stretching, because I think it
would be a lot easier to prove the fairness of an efficient consumer of a
trustworthy entropy stream, than to prove the fairness of any drawing method
with a well-seeded PRNG.

---

**EDIT<sup>2</sup>:**
I don't really know Java, but I put this together:

```
public class MySecureRandom extends java.security.SecureRandom {
    private long m = 1;
    private long r = 0;

    @Override
    public final int nextInt(int n) {
        while (true) {
            if (m < 0x80000000L) {
                m <<= 32;
                r <<= 32;
                r += (long)next(32) - Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            }
            long q = m / n;
            if (r < n * q) {
                int x = (int)(r % n);
                m = q;
                r /= n;
                return x;
            }
            m -= n * q;
            r -= n * q;
        }
    }
}
```

This does away with the greedy default uniform [0,n-1] generator and replaces it with a modified Doctor Jacques version.  Timing a card-shuffle range of values shows almost a 6x speed-up over the `SecureRandom.nextInt(n)`.

My previous version of this code (only 2x speed-up) assumed that `SecureRandom.next(b)` was efficient, but it turns out that call was discarding entropy and dragging the whole loop down.  This version manages its own chunking.

Comment: First link is dead, archived here: https://web.archive.org/web/20200213145912/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65653.html

Answer (score 3):

[Documentation about SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) says it may block waiting for the system to generate more entropy (for instance, in Linux it takes random numbers from /dev/random), so if you are going to use it, maybe you will need some help from hardware: install random number generator card (a hardware device that generates real random numbers, not pseudo-random ones) this way your system will generate random numbers with enough speed so your program doesn't get blocked.

Comment: +1 There are different SecureRandom strategies you can chose from, some use the seed and some don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.security.SecureRandom` as you can use `java.util.Random` for such things.

Only be aware that `java.security.SecureRandom` can depend on some entropy from the computer running the program. If you get to many random values from it then it may block until enough entropy is generated by the computer (e.g. on linux `java.security.SecureRandom` is using `/dev/urandom`).

So if you want to generate many random values and can life with a PRNG use `java.util.Random`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just updated the question with requirements. unfortunately a PRNG is not sufficient.